# How are the block header bytes treated when calculating the block size in weight?

Tags: segregated-witness, block-header, block-weight

In pre-segwit, block header bytes were counted as "1 byte" and participated equally in the block size up to 1MB. Since the header is 80 bytes, we would actually have 999,917 bytes (1,000,000 - 80 header bytes - 3 tx counter bytes) for transactions.

However, what in the case of post-segwit when there is no more calculation at the level of the real byte, but at the level of the WU? Are these header bytes **treated as non-segwit bytes, i.e. cost 4 WU**, so we actually have 3,999,668 WU (4,000,000 - 320 WU for header - 12 WU for tx counter) for transactions?

Does this then mean that, for example, in [this block](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/block/0000000000000000000cbbceb342e07071f9621607e044ec909aa86fcdf88e8a) (click on `Technical details` to see all the block properties I'm talking about) the `weight` (3,992,825 WU) also includes `320` **WU** of header bytes and `12` **WU** of tx counter bytes. Additionally, the `size` (1,159,038 bytes) and `stripped size` (944,929 bytes) also include `80` **bytes** of header and `3` **bytes** of tx counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these header bytes treated as non-segwit bytes, i.e. cost 4 WU, so we actually have 3,999,668 WU (4,000,000 - 320 WU for header - 12 WU for tx counter) for transactions?

Yes. The header weighs 320 weight units. The transaction count is also part of the block serialization, which typically means another 3 vbytes or 12 WU that can't be used for transaction data per se.

The weight of a block is defined as its normal, full, pre-segwit serialized size times 3 plus one time its post-segwit serialized size. The header is included in both of these, and thus counted 4 times overall.

> Does this then mean that, for example, in this block (click on Technical details to see all the block properties I'm talking about) the weight (3,992,825 WU) also includes 320 WU of header bytes and 12 WU of tx counter bytes. Additionally, the size (1,159,038 bytes) and stripped size (944,929 bytes) also include 80 bytes of header and 3 bytes of tx counter?

Exactly right on both counts.

Comment: Transaction count is not a part of a block header?

Comment: No, the block serialization consists of (a) the 80-byte block header, plus (b) the vector of transactions in it. The serialization of that vector consists of (b.1) the number of elements in the vector, plus (b.2) the elements thenselves serialized one by one.

Comment: And what about [`block size`](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch09.asciidoc#structure-of-a-block) as another additional field (4 bytes)? Should we also consider it together with tx count and header?

Comment: No, that's not part of the serialization of a block. It's just what I said above: the header, plus the transactions.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit and included a tx number in the calculation. Is it more accurate now?

Comment: Forgot my previous question, I found an answer, so I deleted it. Just, are the calculations now more accurate (after I edited a question and added a tx number)?

Comment: @ByzantineNode LGTM, but wait for PieterWuille to be sure

Comment: @ByzantineNode BTW tx count field (as you called it) can go from 1 (4 WUI) to 9 (288 WUI) so the amount of WUI left for transactions may vary (it is typically 3 as PieterWuille wrote)

Comment: The tx length field is 1 for up to 252 transactions, 3 for up to 2^16-1, 5 for up to 2^32-1, and 9 for up to 2^64-1. You can't actually have more than ~16000 transactions in a block without exceeding the weight limit, so the tx count is always 1, 3, or exceptionally 5 bytes (4, 12, or 20 WU).

Comment: Thanks to both, so it's mostly 3 bytes (12 WUI). Then the calculation is fine? For the block that I gave as example the `size` (1,159,038) and `stripped size` (944,929 bytes) also contain 80 byte header and 3 byte tx count, i.e. `weight` (3,992,825) also contains 320 WUI for header and 12 WUI for tx count. In global the total amount of WUI available for transactions is 3,999,668 WUI, that is 999,917 vbyte? (all this if we assume tx count as 3 bytes)

Comment: Exactly, but wait for confirmation from PieterWuille to be sure.

Comment: @ByzantineNode Yes, indeed. The tx count is also part of the stripped size, the serialized size, and thus (with a factor 4) also part of the weight, and the tx count serialization is 3 bytes for the block you link above. BTW, weight units are commonly abbreviated to WU (I've never seen WUI).

Comment: Me neither, I used WUI only because he used that term, so as not to confuse him (I assumed he meant WU). Also, @ByzantineNode, the field indicating the number of transactions is most often called `tx counter` instead of `tx count` or `tx number` like you used first.

Comment: Big thanks to both. I edited the question to include those changes.

Comment: @PieterWuille Hey Pieter, since I want to use this question as a reference, could you please just edit your answer (parts of the original question that you used in your answer) to include these new edits added to the question, since WUI has been replaced with WU and a more accurate calculation is now given (we don't have 3,999,680 WU for txs, but, as written now, 3,999,668 WU etc.). I don't want to change your answer myself, it seems rude to me. Thanks

Comment: @PieterWuille I did the edit myself, hope that's ok?